# Odoo API Dynamically Load Data to Different Instances

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

Anyone here knows how to post data to 2 different instances of Odoo at the same time? Below is my codebase

```
for key,value in customers.items(): 
    for val in value:
          models.execute_kw(db,uid,password,'res.partner','create',[
            {
              "contact_type": val['contact_type'],
              "mobile": val['mobile'],
              "name": val['name'],
              "phone": val['phone'],
              "ref": val['ref'],
              "state_id":val['state_id'],
              "x_studio_after_sales_sc_suppor":val['sc_name'],
              "x_studio_birthday": val['x_studio_birthday'],
              "x_studio_genre": val['x_studio_genre'],
              "x_studio_spoken_language":val['lang_name'],
              "company_id":2,
            }
          ])
```

I want to dynamically load customer information to the 2 instances by just changing the *company_id* field value; 1 for default instance and 2 for the second instance. My codebase so far is able to load data to the default instance, the second instance throws permission errors. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

In that case you have to check if your user has rights to write for second company. `user -> Allowed Companies`

Also all related objects have to be accessible to by second company. (i cant see any relations from your example)

Comment: but the database connection when you activate developer mode is one, not 2.

Comment: you have multicompany, but one database ?

Comment: no, they are different. what I meant to say is when I activate developer mode I can only see one db instance that i use to authenticate my login. This does not change even if I switch instance from one company to another